# SQL Server debugging: break on error?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, sql-server-2008

I can't find any debug options when debugging an SP in SSMS on SQL 2008. Is it possible to have it break at the point when an error occurs, so I can examine where exactly the error is thrown and what the values of variables are at that point?

The error I'm trying to debug is:

Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Procedure xxx, Line 58
String or binary data would be truncated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint early on you can step through until you find the error.

As a heads-up though, you need to be looking for a case where you're putting a string into a varchar that's longer than the varchar allows.

So, if you have a varcahr(5) and you try and set it to be 'mylongtext' you'll get that error.

---

To do this in SSMS, right click on the SP and choose EXECUTE TO > New Window. This will create the execute code for you:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @LocationID int
DECLARE @SiteID int

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = [MY-DB].[dbo].[P_SELECT_RetrieveToolTips] 
   @LocationID
  ,@SiteID
GO
```

Move cursor to the `EXECUTE` statement and press F9 to add a breakpoint.

Then press play (debug). When it stops on the breakpoint, press F11 to step into the SProc and then F10 to step along each line.

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar w/ the error message but this is a LONG sp that I inherited, with several temp tables etc. So finding exactly where it's happening is rather difficult...

Comment: The line number in the error message should help narrow it down a bit though? Together with the step-into debugging - you should be able to get all the variable at around that time?

Comment: Yeah those line numbers are highly confusing :) Line 58 is blank. If I start counting from the BEGIN statement, Line 58 is a DECLARE @Variable DATETIME. There are a few VARCHAR(100) variables near there too though. Where does Line 58 start counting from? Seems odd it doesn't break _when_ the error occurs instead of when it's declared!

Comment: hmm, yeah I know what you mean. I don't think there's a way of breaking on error. Looks like a long night with a beer and a finger on the F10 key :-)

Comment: So it turns out that I wasn't paying enough attention, the line number issued wasn't in the SP I was calling; it was in a secondary SP which was being called from that one. And in that SP, line 58 was indeed selecting one varchar field into a smaller one. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sql Query Analyzer for that. Your message means you are trying to save some value in a field, which length is smaller than the length of that value.